# typescript - test case for invalid arguments in jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm very new to `jasmine` and writing test cases.
So i have this scenario where i have a function like below in `typescript`

```
someFunction(value: number){
   return isNaN(value) ? value : value * 3;
}
```

while trying to write test cases  when the `value` is a `number` its fine. But i want to write a test case for the scenario where the `value` is `NaN` say string. In the later case i get error while while writing the code i.e

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type number.

That's a valid error. Because i'm trying to pass a `string` to a function that expects a `number`.

I'm not able to figure out how to write a test case for this scenario.

One possible solution for this is declaring the type of parameter as `any` like below.

```
someFunction(value: any){
   return isNaN(value) ? value : value * 3;
}
```

I would still like to know is there a better way to achieve what i'm trying to do or just changing the type to `any` is my last option.

Comment: call `someFunction("myValue" as any)`.

Comment: Thanks that's sounds logical instead of changing my function signature.

Answer (score -1):

If you actually want to do this then you can declare your own overload

```
declare function isNaN(value: string): boolean;
```

While this works, it is likely better practice to be explicit as by writing

```
if (Number.isNaN(Number(value)) {...}
```

Comment: Downvoter please comment. Explain how this can be improved. It is certainly not incorrect.